# Creating a set of radio buttons from a context

Tags: django

I want to send a list `y` as a context to a template. Then, for each element `x` in `y`, I want to create a radio button in the template. Each radio button should have its `value` attribute equal to `x` for when I want to process the submitted form, and the label for this radio button should also be set to `x`.

In the view, for sending the context to the template, I have:

```
y = [0] * 10
for i in range(0, 10):
    y[i] = # assign to some value
context = {'y': names}
return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

Then in the template, I've tried a few things to try to display these radio buttons as I want, but nothing seems to quite work. For example:

```
<form>    
    {% for x in y %}
        <label><input type="radio" name="group1" value=x>x</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

outputs a set of radio buttons whose labels are simply the text "x", rather than its value from the list `y`. What needs to be done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use {{ variable_name }}. Like this:

```
<form>    
{% for x in y %}
    <label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="{{ x }}">{{ x }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
```

What happened is that you didn't use Django template sintax and just wrote a valid html label, hence the x in the radio buttons