# Sending a list as a context variable and back again via POST

Tags: django

Suppose in my view, I have a list of strings, which I send as a context variable to a template. Then in that template, there is a form which is submitted. One of the fields on that form is a hidden field, and set to equal this list from the context. Back in my view, when I then read this list from the request's POST object, the list seems to have separated out all the characters from the original list, and set each character to its own element.

For example, if my original list is ['alpha', 'beta'], then the list returned from my template via the request's POST object appears as ['a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'b', 'e', 't', 'a'].

1) Why does this happen?

2) How can I keep the original format?

Here's the relevant code from my template:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="class_names" value="{{ class_names }}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

where `class_names` is the list passed as a context variable in the view:

```
class_names = ['alpha', 'beta']
context = {'class_names': class_names}
return render(request, 'teacher/query.html', context)
```

and then in the view when I extract this list from the request:

```
class_names = request.POST['class_names']
for x in _class_names:
    print x
```

it prints out each individual character, rather than each word in the list.

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: I would use a comma separated string as value: "alpha, beta" and then convert them back to a list with split(",")

Comment: If I use a comma separated string, then how can I access the individual elements in the template?

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:
View:

UPDATE: You can use two variables like this:

```
class_names_for_radio = ['alpha', 'beta']
class_names = ','.join(class_names_for_radio)

context = {'class_names': class_names,
           'class_names_for_radio': class_names_for_radio}
return render(request, 'teacher/query.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="class_names" value="{{ class_names }}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When you receive the value:

```
class_names = request.POST['class_names'].split(',') #unsafe, just a demo
for x in _class_names:
    print x
```

Comment: That sounds like it could solve the problem, but actually what I want to do is to take each element in this list and process it in the template. How can I do this if the elements are concatenated into a string?

Comment: What do you want to do with them in the template? I assumed you used them in a hidden input from your code... Do you want to have several inputs?

Comment: As well as sending them back as a hidden input, I also want to create a set of radio buttons, one for each element in this list. You can see this in a related problem I had here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496940/creating-a-set-of-radio-buttons-from-a-context/24497040#24497040

Comment: Well... you could use two variables in the context.. See the update

Comment: The Alpha and Beta were just to demonstrate; in fact, the list can be of various sizes, so it has to be a list rather than a fixed number of elements.

Comment: Will work in any case :P.. Key concept: I would use a different variable to store the list for iteration in the template

Comment: But how can I create a context with an arbitrary number of elements in the list?

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate in what you want to do, instead of how. class_names_for_radio can be an arbitrary list